# trying to add a author value in wp page links?

Tags: pages, tags, author

```
function wp_link_pages_titled($args = '',$name,$author) {
    $defaults = array(
        'before' => '<p>' . __('Pages:'), 
        'after' => '</p>',
        'link_before' => '', 
        'link_after' => '',
        'echo' => 1
    );

    $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    extract( $r, EXTR_SKIP );

    global $page, $numpages, $multipage, $more, $pagenow, $pages;

    $output = '';
    if ( $multipage ) {
        $output .= $before;
        for ( $i = 1; $i < ($numpages+1); $i = $i + 1 ) {
            $part_content = $pages[$i-1];
            $has_part_title = strpos( $part_content, '<!--pagetitle:' );
            if( 0 === $has_part_title ) {
                $end = strpos( $part_content, '-->' );
                $title = trim( str_replace( '<!--pagetitle:', '', substr( $part_content, 0, $end ) ) );
            }

        $part_content2 = $pages[$i-1];
            $has_part_title2 = strpos( $part_content2, '<!--pageauthor:' );
             if( 1 === $has_part_title ) {
                $end2 = strpos( $part_content2, '-->' );
                $title2 = trim( str_replace( '<!--pageauthor:', '', substr( $part_content2, 0, $end2 ) ) );
            }

            $output .= '<tr><td class="category2_td1">Mirror '.$i.'</td><td class="category2_td1">';
            if ( ($i != $page) || ((!$more) && ($page==1)) ) {
                $output .= _wp_link_page($i);
            }

            $title = isset( $title ) && ( strlen( $title ) > 0 ) ? $title : $name;

            $title2 = isset( $title2 ) && ( strlen( $title2 ) > 0 ) ? $title2 : $author;
            $output .= $link_before . $title . $link_after;
            if ( ($i != $page) || ((!$more) && ($page==1)) )
                $output .= '</a></td><td class="category2_td1">'.$title2.'</td></tr>';
        else
                $output .= '</td><td class="category2_td1">'.$title2.'</td></tr>';
        }
        $output .= $after;
    }
    if ( $echo )
        echo $output;
    return $output;
}
```

I'm trying to allow the adding of the author name to the post with the use of the wp link pages tag
so it is like this

```
<!--nextpage--><!--pagetitle: daily --><!--pageauthor: dan -->
```

the original code which works for these tags

```
<!--nextpage--><!--pagetitle: daily -->

function wp_link_pages_titled($args = '',$name) {
    $defaults = array(
        'before' => '<p>' . __('Pages:'), 
        'after' => '</p>',
        'link_before' => '', 
        'link_after' => '',
        'echo' => 1
    );

    $r = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    extract( $r, EXTR_SKIP );

    global $page, $numpages, $multipage, $more, $pagenow, $pages;

    $output = '';
    if ( $multipage ) {
        $output .= $before;
        for ( $i = 1; $i < ($numpages+1); $i = $i + 1 ) {
            $part_content = $pages[$i-1];
            $has_part_title = strpos( $part_content, '<!--pagetitle:' );
            if( 0 === $has_part_title ) {
                $end = strpos( $part_content, '-->' );
                $title = trim( str_replace( '<!--pagetitle:', '', substr( $part_content, 0, $end ) ) );
            }
            $output .= ' ';
            if ( ($i != $page) || ((!$more) && ($page==1)) ) {
                $output .= _wp_link_page($i);
            }
            $title = isset( $title ) && ( strlen( $title ) > 0 ) ? $title : $name;
            $output .= $link_before . $title . $link_after;
            if ( ($i != $page) || ((!$more) && ($page==1)) )
                $output .= '</a>';
        }
        $output .= $after;
    }
    if ( $echo )
        echo $output;
    return $output;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas how to add the extra author tag for `<!--nextpage-->` tag?

Answer (score 1):

You check for `<!--pageauthor:`, but you expect it to start on the second character (`1 === $has_part_title2`) (you even have a typo there and left the `2` off). This will not work, because `<!--pagetitle:` is still part of that string (you don't chop it off).

You should either chop it off (do a substring in `$part_content2 = $pages[$i-1]`), or allow it to appear later in the post (`false !== $has_part_title2`).

```
$has_part_title2 = strpos( $part_content2, '<!--pageauthor:' );
if( false !== $has_part_title2 ) {
    $end2 = strpos( $part_content2, '-->' );
    $title2 = trim( str_replace( '<!--pageauthor:', '', substr( $part_content2, 0, $end2 ) ) );
}
```

Comment: okay I'm not that great at php so I'm a bit confused on how to do it

Comment: @user7715: I updated my answer with a lines that you should change.

Comment: doesn't work<!--nextpage--><!--pagetitle: daily --><!--pageauthor: dan --> the pagetitle works but the page author does not